# Translation from Matlab to R with system(sprintf())

Tags: r, matlab

I am trying to translate the following matlab code to R:

```
clear all
nsta = [1,2,3];
npx  = [2,3,4,5];
npu  = [2,3,4,5];
nmax = 2500;
nome = 'MODEL1b';
system(sprintf('del %s.log',nome));
nfiles = 0;
for k = 1:length(nsta)
    for i = 1:length(npx)
        for j = 1:length(npu)
            nx = nsta(k);
            npar = (npx(i)^nx)*npu(j);
            if (npar < nmax)
                nfiles = nfiles+1;
                system(sprintf('copy %s%d%d%d.txt  %s.txt',nome,nx,npx(i),npu(j),nome));
                system(sprintf('copy input%d%d%d.txt  input.txt',nx,npx(i),npu(j)));
                system(sprintf('copy template%d%d%d.txt template.txt',nx,npx(i),npu(j)));
                tic;
                system(sprintf('RFuzzy %s',nome));
                time = toc;
                fprintf('Arquivo: %d    Config: %d%d%d    Time: %f',nfiles,nx,npx(i),npu(j),toc);
                system(sprintf('copy min.txt min%d%d%d.txt',nx,npx(i),npu(j)));
            end
        end
    end
end
```

I tried the following code in R:

```
rm(list = ls())
nsta <- c(1,2,3)
npx <- c(2,3,4,5)
npu <- c(2,3,4,5)
nmax <- 2500
nome <- "MODEL1b"
system(sprintf('del %s.log', nome))
nfiles <- 0
for(k in 1:length(nsta)){
  for(i in 2:length(npx)){
    for(j in 2:length(npu)){
      nx <- nsta[k]
      npar <- (npx[i]^nx)*npu[j]
      if(npar < nmax){
        nfiles <- nfiles + 1
        system(sprintf('copy %s%d%d%d.txt  %s.txt',nome,nx,npx[i],npu[j],nome))
        system(sprintf('copy input%d%d%d.txt  input.txt',nx,npx[i],npu[j]))
        system(sprintf('copy template%d%d%d.txt template.txt',nx,npx[i],npu[j]))
        system(sprintf('RFuzzy %s',nome))
        fprintf('Arquivo: %d    Config: %d%d%d    Time: %f',nfiles,nx,npx[i],npu[j])
        system(sprintf('copy min.txt min%d%d%d.txt',nx,npx[i],npu[j]))
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But when it runs the seventh line it gives me the following advice

```
Warning message:
running command 'del MODEL1b.log' had status 127
```

Apparently, it is not running my code already in the seventh line. Any help to translate it properly?

Comment: `unlink(paste0(nome, '.log'))`

Comment: Status 127 means that the command isn't found: in this case `del`.

Comment: `del` command is delimiter. What should be the answer for that then?

Comment: `del` should be found by the system, i.e. it should be in the PATH. You could also provide a direct path to `del`.